# Run TPCC on local cockroachdb cluster

Tags: cockroachdb

I have a local cockroachdb up and running by following instructions from https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/stable/start-a-local-cluster.html

I am trying to run the tpcc benchmark following the instructions from https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/stable/performance-benchmarking-with-tpc-c.html

It looks like the TPCC binary `workload.LATEST` assumes the cluster is on google cloud; and so it issues the following error:

```
$ ./workload.LATEST fixtures load tpcc --warehouses=1000 "postgres://root@localhost:26257?sslmode=disable"
```

> Error: failed to create google cloud client (You may need to setup the GCS application default credentials: 'gcloud auth application-default login --project=cockroach-shared'): dialing: google: could not find default credentials. See https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/application-default-credentials for more information.

What can I change to run the benchmark?

Answer (score 1):

If you upgrade to v2.1, workload is a built-in command and you can run it with your cluster, it does not make google cloud assumption: https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/stable/cockroach-workload.html

Answer (score 0):

It's not nearly as fast as using the fixtures stored in Google Cloud, but you can load the data into your cluster using normal SQL statements by running something like:

```
workload init tpcc --warehouses=1000
```

Note that while I'm not sure exactly how long it will take to load 1000 warehouses in this way locally, I expect it will take quite some time.